# How to add a variable and assign a value based on the value of another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new variable (`final_session`) and assign a value based on
the filtered value of another variable which is in date format (`date`).
I have been able to add the variable
and assign a value, then been able to filter and change the value of the
variable, but I lose the rest of the observations (which I do not want to do).

I have the code below:

```r
## add `final_session` column, defualt value 0
old_sp_long2 <- old_sp_long %>% add_column(final_session = 0)


## select most recent date of sessions 1--15 and mark as final session == 1
df <- old_sp_long2 %>%
    filter(wave <= 15) %>%
    group_by(uci) %>%
    slice(which.max(date)) %>%
    mutate(final_session = replace(final_session, final_session == 0, 1))
```

I minimal dataset below:

```r
structure(list(uci = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("10001h", 
"10268h", "10431h"), class = "factor"), wave = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), date = structure(c(17042, 17053, 
17060, 17074, 17086, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 17003, 17010, 17015, 17055, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16994, 17000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), session = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L))
```

I'm sure this is possible but I just cannot figure it out. Does anyone have a
solution to my problem? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)

old_sp_long2 %>%
  group_by(uci) %>%
  mutate(max_date = max(date[wave <= 15], na.rm = TRUE), 
         max_wave = wave[which.max(date == max_date)],
         final_session = replace(final_session, date == max_date, 1))


#   uci     wave date       session final_session max_date   max_wave
#   <fct>  <int> <date>       <int>         <dbl> <date>        <int>
# 1 10001h     1 2016-08-29       1             0 2016-10-12        5
# 2 10001h     2 2016-09-09       2             0 2016-10-12        5
# 3 10001h     3 2016-09-16       3             0 2016-10-12        5
# 4 10001h     4 2016-09-30       4             0 2016-10-12        5
# 5 10001h     5 2016-10-12       5             1 2016-10-12        5
# 6 10001h     6 NA               6             0 2016-10-12        5
# 7 10001h     7 NA              NA             0 2016-10-12        5
# 8 10001h     8 NA              NA             0 2016-10-12        5
# 9 10001h     9 NA              NA             0 2016-10-12        5
#10 10001h    10 NA              NA             0 2016-10-12        5
# … with 41 more rows
```

This keeps same number of observation as in your original `old_sp_long2`.

Comment: That's excellent and works, thanks so much! For my own learning, can you please explain what you did, for example, what do the square brackets in `date[wave <= 15] ` mean. What is the purpose of adding these extra variables (`max_date`, `max_wave`)? Also, is there a more efficient way to do this i.e., without adding the first adding the `final_session` variable?

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski In your approach you are using `filter(wave <= 15)` so we are interested only in values where `wave <= 15` hence, we select only those `date` variables in `date[wave <= 15]` . I added `max_date` and `max_wave` so as to not to override your existing variables. The above answer would work with `old_sp_long` as well i.e without using `add_column`. Just change `old_sp_long2` in above answer to `old_sp_long`.